# Capturar datos con JavaScript y método POST

Tags: javascript, html, post

Intento capturar datos de un formulario enviado desde un HTML con método POST, a otro HTML y procesarlo desde un JavaScript, pero al intentar ejecutarlo me dice que la página no esta disponible

Este es mi código HTML

```
<form action="html/opciones.html" method="POST">
    <div class="container-pizzas">
        <div class="container principal pizza-tamanio">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h5 class="tamanio-title"></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <select class="form-select">
                        <option selected>Grande</option>
                        <option value="1">Pequeña</option>
                        <option value="2">Mediana</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Botón para ingredientes de pizza -->
    <div class="container-md">
        <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" id="opciones" hidden>
                Cargar Opciones
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

En mi JavaScript sin poner ninguna instrucción de lectura y/o otra cosa, me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error solo se ejecuta si mando el formulario por método POST

Comment: Error 405: esto significa "Método no permitido". Tu servidor no acepta POST para esa URL, no es un problema de Javascript

Comment: En el atributo action del formulario tienes un archivo `.html`. No puedes enviar datos por POST ni por ningún otro método HTTP a archivos .html, porque los mismos están del lado del cliente.   Estos métodos son para comunicarse con el servidor, por tanto tienen que ser enviados a archivos con extensión `.php`